# Comparing against 0 in for checking condition in Python and C

Tags: python, c

```
def testfun(testValue):
    power = 20
    for i in range(0, 10):
        z = testValue/(10.0**i)
        print("Iteration: "+str(i)+" , z: "+str(z))
        if ( z <= 0 ):
            power = i
            break
    return power
testfun(9000)
```

I wrote a small program to find the smallest integer for which the value (in this case 9000) passed into the function called "testfun" as argument divided by power of 10 raised to that integer will be less than zero.

However the value returns to me 20 when it should return to me 4 (when testValue = 9000).

I experienced the same problem in C while programming Arduino, I tried to test it in Python too, but I am getting the same problem.

Can some give me an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

As you used `10.0` that is a float you need you must use Floor Division (`//` ) instead `/` or add  `from __future__ import division` at the top level of your code  :

```py
def testfun(testValue):
  power = 20
  for i in range(0, 10):
    z = testValue//(10.0**i) # or use z = testValue/(10**i)
    #print("Iteration: "+str(i)+" , z: "+str(z))
    if ( z <= 0 ):
        power = i
        break
  return power

print testfun(9000)
```

result :

```py
4
```

> Floor Division - The division of operands where the result is the quotient in which the digits after the decimal point are removed.

Also in `C` you need to use `floor` that convert the result of division to double :

```py
floor(a/b)
```

Comment: What do you mean I should use "//" ? What does that do? And why does using "/" create the problem to begin with?

Comment: @redilhom, `/` returns float and `//` integer

Comment: Any idea how to overcome the same problem in C?

Comment: You told me a solution but didn't explain the problem with my code!

Comment: @redilhom see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/ for find a good  explain about your  problem

Comment: Okay I understood how to make it work but you didn't explain why my code is wrong. I need to understand that, that's the whole point of asking this question. My code should implement the same result which you got using the floor division!

Comment: @redilhom i add it to answer , its because of that you are using 10.0 , use 10  ewith `/` then see that result will be 4 again

Comment: @redilhom Please understand that Stack Overflow users are not your private teachers. When the answer says you must use ``//`` in place of ``/``, you are supposed to find out the rest yourself (RTFM). You were able to write the original code, so...

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try `math.floor`:

```
import math
def testfun(testValue):
    power = 20
    for i in range(0, 10):
        z = math.floor(testValue / (10.0**i))
        print("Iteration: "+str(i)+" , z: "+str(z))
        if ( z == 0 ):
            power = i
            break
    return power
print testfun(9000)
```

Output:

```
Iteration: 0 , z: 9000.0
Iteration: 1 , z: 900.0
Iteration: 2 , z: 90.0
Iteration: 3 , z: 9.0
Iteration: 4 , z: 0.0
4
```

In your code your calculation is accurate with float type. Which will lead more steps, but floor only get the integer part and Round down. So, 0.05 means 0. If you use `int()` will get same result:

```
import math
def testfun(testValue):
    power = 20
    for i in range(0, 10):
        z = int(testValue / (10.0**i))
        print("Iteration: "+str(i)+" , z: "+str(z))
        if ( z == 0 ):
            power = i
            break
    return power
print testfun(9000)
```

Output:

```
Iteration: 0 , z: 9000
Iteration: 1 , z: 900
Iteration: 2 , z: 90
Iteration: 3 , z: 9
Iteration: 4 , z: 0
4
```

If you try this code with `(10**i)` will be same:

```
def testfun(testValue):
    power = 20
    for i in range(0, 10):
        z = testValue / (10**i)
        print("Iteration: "+str(i)+" , z: "+str(z))
        if ( z == 0 ):
            power = i
            break
    return power
print testfun(9000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for `z<1` instead of `z<=0`. This works also in C.

```
def testfun(testValue):
  power = 20
  for i in range(0, 10):
      z = testValue/(10.0**i)
      print("Iteration: "+str(i)+" , z: "+str(z))
      if ( z < 1 ):
          power = i
          break
  return power

print(testfun(9000))
```

Result:

```
Iteration: 0 , z: 9000.0
Iteration: 1 , z: 900.0
Iteration: 2 , z: 90.0
Iteration: 3 , z: 9.0
Iteration: 4 , z: 0.9
4
```

If you use `//` instead of `/` it results in:

```
Iteration: 0 , z: 9000.0
Iteration: 1 , z: 900.0
Iteration: 2 , z: 90.0
Iteration: 3 , z: 9.0
Iteration: 4 , z: 0.0
4
```